# Database Query - One to Many

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am sure this questions has been answered before, but I have no idea what to search for.

I have 2 tables (coming from Wordpress), Users and User Meta Data. I need to create a query that takes the Meta Data and includes that with the other user data. I am developing independent solution in MS Access that will use WP data, so I cannot use any Wordpress specific functions.

Basically, I need to take these 2 tables:

```
user_id | username
-------------------
   01   |  bob24
   02   |  james112


meta_id | user_id |  meta_key  | meta_value
-----------------------------------------
01      | 01      | first_name | Bob
02      | 01      | last_name  | Smith
03      | 02      | first_name | James
04      | 02      | last_name  | Jones
```

And turn it into this:

```
user_id | username | first_name | last_name
-----------------------------------------
01      | bob24    | Bob        | Smith
02      | james112 | James      | Jones
```

I am sure there is a word for this, but I don't know what it is called. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for the word "`join`".

Comment: Can a join query do that kind of operation? I'm not sure how I could make that work. Sorry for such a basic question. I'm sure the answer is really simple.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for might be pivot? You are turning row data into columns.

Comment: Thank you @MattFellows, that is exactly what I mean. I guess a join query is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for @GolezTrol for pointing me in the right direction. I did need to pivot the data. I searched and Access has this feature. I created a "cross-tab query." Here is the query in case anyone else has the same problem.

```
TRANSFORM Last(meta.meta_value) AS LastOfmeta_value
SELECT meta.[user_id], Last(meta.[umeta_id]) AS [Total Of umeta_id]
FROM meta
GROUP BY meta.[user_id]
PIVOT meta.[meta_key];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for *pivot table*, which is a slow and complex process in MySQL. 
If you like to read more about that, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

But since you seem to have exactly two fields, maybe a join will do just fine for you.
To do it with a join, join the meta table twice. Once for the first name and once for the last name:

```
select
  u.user_id,
  u.username,
  fn.meta_value as first_name,
  ln.meta_value as last_name
from
  User u
  left join Meta fn on fn.user_id = u.user_id and fn.meta_key = 'first_name'
  left join Meta ln on ln.user_id = u.user_id and ln.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

If you want to have only those users that do indeed have a last name, you can change the join to an inner join, which might be slightly faster too.

Comment: So I tried the pivot table in Access and it showed the data how I need it to appear in a query. I'll try the join you suggested.

Comment: Access says that there is a syntax error and I can't pin it down. And ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I suppose Access is too polite to suggest what the syntax error might be.

Comment: Access? Sorry, I based my answer on MySQL since that was the (first) database that was mentioned in the tags. :-) I took the liberty of removing it from the tags now, and `wordpress` as well, since you explicitly state that it needs to be independent from Wordpress.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that you have two table name with meta and user

```
SELECT username
    , meta.meta_value
    , user_id
FROM user
INNER JOIN WHERE user.user_id = meta.user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this didn't work at all. I got an error and changed it to "INNER JOIN meta ON ..." Still nothing.